# bootstrap form inside panel layout looks wrong

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I have a form defined inside a bootstrap panel, then the form group layout goes to pieces.

[image]

I coloured the form red so that I could see where it was ;) here's the jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

I have found that if I add

```
.panel-body .form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

to the css, I then get this

[image]

(I coloured the form red so that I could see where it was ;) )

so it looks like it's fixed, but seems a terrible hack to me

- Is this is a bug in bootstrap
- Do I just have to apply this css
- Is there something wrong with my form definitions ?

thanks

Comment: arrghh! lost the jsFiddle. new one is at https://jsfiddle.net/g437m8ve/2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to bootstrap docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-horizontal), the class `form-horizontal` makes `<form>` act like a `.row` so you don't need to add it and have `.col-**-*` in from groups, label and stuff. The docs give you an example o

But you have a `.row` inside a `.row` and no `.col-**-*`. `.row` has negative margin to delete the padding of his parent so with no `.col-**-*` as parent it has 2 negative margins.

So it's kind of messy. I suggest removing your `.row` and `.form-horizontal` class to achieve the look you want or add the margin like you already did.

[Here it's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g437m8ve/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the other answer for pointing me in the right direction. I personally like the option of adding a column with 12 width that wraps around the other form-groups.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" style="background: red;">
    <div class="col col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>field 1</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>field 2</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fshavxvg/)